# Installation issue with dual boot

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, install, error

I have an error when I try to dual boot Odin alongside windows 10. It says:

`ERROR: configuring bootloader error: command failed with exit status: exit status 1`

I tried several solutions that I found over the internet but none of them is working. Here is a link to the video of the error screen of the installer, in case it helps:
https://we.tl/t-DPYWJyRpas

Comment: Just to be clear. Did you try to boot into windows, go into Settings>Update & Security > Recovery > Advanced startup > Restart Now and open the live usb from there?

Comment: Yes sure, I created swap, boot and root partitions but it keeps giving me this error